# MySQL - SEC_TO_TIME giving same result, regardless of the group

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, time

Using below query in order to get sum of time differential per month. Basically I ahve a start time, stop time. I take the difference which equals running time, and then Id like to sum all running time up for a month, to say that in January we had x hours y minutes and z seconds of runtime.

However, when summing the values, I experience weird results. When summing the seconds for January and February. I get different results. Then when converting the seconds into a timestamp, they resolve to the same time value.

Query 1

---

```
select sum(TIME_TO_SEC(diff)) as "total runtime" from
(SELECT
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(stp_time,3)="DUR"
        THEN
            TIMEDIFF(LEFT(stp_time,8), '00:00:00')
        ELSE
            TIMEDIFF(
                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(stp_date," ",LEFT(stp_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(str_date," ",LEFT(str_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s')
                )
    END AS diff, ext_umid, str_date
FROM vms1_asrun
where str_date like "%JAN%") as a
```

Result For `"%JAN%"` ---> [image]

Result for `"%FEB%"` ---> [image]

### Query 2

```
select monthname(STR_TO_DATE(STR_DATE, "%d/%b/%Y")) as month,
SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(diff)))
                 from 
(SELECT
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(stp_time,3)="DUR"
        THEN
            TIMEDIFF(LEFT(stp_time,8), '00:00:00')
        ELSE
            TIMEDIFF(
                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(stp_date," ",LEFT(stp_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
                STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(str_date," ",LEFT(str_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s')
                )
    END AS diff, ext_umid, str_date
FROM vms1_asrun) as a
group by month
```

Results are given the same for each month (Except december which has a significant less amount of data)

[image]

Comment: I guess you are hitting the limit of SEC_TO_TIME which can only display hours, minutes and seconds - so if your SUM() is larger than 24 hours, you always get this result! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time

Comment: sum of runtimes will most likely be in the 1000s of hours. Is there an alternate solution?

Comment: I guess  I could just convert it myself :(

Comment: Can you answer your question yourself now? If yes, please do so and please give a detailed explanation!

Comment: got caught up on another task, incoming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the current query I am using. Due to the limitations of maximum TIME object value, long running timecodes were not accessible.
The workaround I have chosen is to simply display the hours taken, as oposed to a timestamp

```
 select monthname(STR_TO_DATE(STR_DATE, "%d/%b/%Y")) as month,
    sum(TIME_TO_SEC(diff))/3600 as hours
                     from 
    (SELECT
        CASE WHEN RIGHT(stp_time,3)="DUR"
            THEN
                TIMEDIFF(LEFT(stp_time,8), '00:00:00')
            ELSE
                TIMEDIFF(
                    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(stp_date," ",LEFT(stp_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s'),
                    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(str_date," ",LEFT(str_time,8)), '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s')
                    )
        END AS diff, ext_umid, str_date
    FROM vms1_asrun) as a
    group by month
```